# Two copy buttons for two different textareas

Tags: javascript, html, copy

I am new at javascript. I have a problem with a simple script. I have searched the internet for a long time and I seriously can't see what I'm doing wrong. It's probably just me who can't think right now.
The problem is that when I click on 'copy 1'-button it copies textarea 2...

```html
<textarea id="html" name="html">textarea 1</textarea>
<input type="button" value="Copy 1" onclick="copy_to_clipboard(html);"><br><br><br>
<textarea id="test" name="htmltest">textarea 2</textarea>
<input type="button" value="Copy 2" onclick="copy_to_clipboard(test);">

<script>
function copy_to_clipboard(html)
{
    document.getElementById('html').select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
}
function copy_to_clipboard(test)
{
    document.getElementById('test').select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
}
</script>
```

I'm trying to have two different textarea with each a copy button...

Comment: Two function with same name ? Just pass the separate ids as the parameters of the function and use is there. It is the sole purpose of functions to use the same code again.

Comment: You have two functions with the same name.

Comment: Thanks... As i said. It's just me who can't think right now! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is because of you have created two functions with same name and same parameter. You have to do this:

```js
function copy_to_clipboard(ids)
{
    document.getElementById(ids).select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
}
```

```html
<textarea id="html" name="html">textarea 1</textarea>
<input type="button" value="Copy 1" onclick="copy_to_clipboard('html');"><br><br><br>
<textarea id="test" name="htmltest">textarea 2</textarea>
<input type="button" value="Copy 2" onclick="copy_to_clipboard('test');">
```

And the parameter passed in function, at the time of function called, must be in quota mark. Check in HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

You are using same function name in both the cases. Please find my updated snippet

```html
<textarea id="html" name="html">textarea 1</textarea>
<input type="button" value="Copy 1" onclick="copy_to_clipboard_1(html);"><br><br><br>
<textarea id="test" name="htmltest">textarea 2</textarea>
<input type="button" value="Copy 2" onclick="copy_to_clipboard(test);">

<script>
function copy_to_clipboard_1(html)
{
    document.getElementById('html').select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
}
function copy_to_clipboard(test)
{
    document.getElementById('test').select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why use two functions. Just pass the ids and use that there.

Comment: solved the problem but not a good way. Try to do with only one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have two functions with same name. There is no need to make two different functions. Also, use argument that you passed in that function instead of hardcoding id name individually. Pass the argument using inverted commas in 'onclick' function.

```html
<textarea id="html" name="html">textarea 1</textarea>
<input type="button" value="Copy 1" onclick="copy_to_clipboard('html');"><br><br><br>
<textarea id="test" name="htmltest">textarea 2</textarea>
<input type="button" value="Copy 2" onclick="copy_to_clipboard('test');">

<script>
function copy_to_clipboard(html)
{
    document.getElementById(html).select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
}
</script>
```